# Does RxJava Parallelization Break the Observable Contract?

Tags: multithreading, parallel-processing, reactive-programming, rx-java

Ben Christensen [posted here](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/issues/1673) that the best way to currently achieve parallelism in RxJava is to create another `Observable` and subscribe it on a scheduler as shown below.

```
streamOfItems.flatMap(item -> {
   doStuffWithItem(item).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io());
});
```

However, the [Observable Contract](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Implementing-Your-Own-Operators#other-considerations) says that an `onNext()` call may be called any number of times, as long as the calls do not overlap. Well, any operators in the rest of the chain following the one above could now easily break that rule (unless they explicitly do some sort of synchronization/serialization).

My impression is RxJava prefers to keep a stream of emissions on one thread at a time and switching a steady sequential stream from one thread to another at specific operators, but never in parallel (as depicted below).

```
observeOn() thread     -------------------------Y----Y----Y-------------
subscribeOn() thread   ----X----X----X----X-----------------------------
```

With a parallel approach, I understand the chart may look something like this and that looks pretty overlapped to me.

```
par subscribeOn() thread 3    -------------------------Y-----Y---------------
par subscribeOn() thread 2    ---------------------------Y---Y---------------
par subscribeOn() thread 1    -------------------------Y-------------Y-------
initial subscribeOn() thread  ----X----X----X----X---------------------------
```

Did I misunderstand anything or make broad assumptions? Is parallelism not breaking the `Observable` contract? Does that make it not preferable in some way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using standard operators, nothing will break the Observable contract because whenever concurrency may happen, the operators serialize their output. In your example, `flatMap` does this so its output is guaranteed to be sequential (although the the reception thread may switch back and forth).

This is, however, not generally true for different stages of the same pipeline if those are separated by an asynchronous boundary or an operator that may do thread arbitration.

Comment: Okay that makes more sense now... So do most operators do serialization even simple ones like map(), or only the ones that need it like flatMap()?

Comment: Operators that don't deal with multiple sources or with scheduler don't themselves do serialization but let the events pass through as they are. Therefore, if there is a rogue source that calls onNext concurrently, map will happily pass that along. To fix such sources, you need to apply `.serialize()` on it.

Comment: Do rogue sources put any built-in operators at risk due to thread safety issues? Like toList()?

Comment: `toList` uses ArrayList.add and thus has the same effect as you'd do it manually and concurrently. Almost all operators can break if the contract is not held.

Comment: That's exactly what I reasoned... thank you! I can see why the parallel() operator was deprecated and removed because its easy to misunderstand and misuse.